# Server 2008 Firewall Blocked Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, remote, windows-firewall

While i was configuring windows firewall in Server 2008, i have accidentally blocked "all programs access". Now i am unable to access to my server with remote desktop also.

My server is not a dedicated machine, it is a virtual machine. Is it possible to gain access to my server again with my provider(seller) support?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have physical access to this machine (I.E., through the host), or is it a hosted solution?  Even if it's a VM, ideally you'd have some sort of "remote console" access where you can still have remote access that is not dependent on RDP.

Comment: Hi, physical access is not possible(hosted solution). My provider didn't give me any remote console information, i will ask. By the way i have blocked all program access to this server. I am afraid that firewall can also block that console too.

Comment: A true remote console will act as a virtual KVM, and doesn't need any special support from the OS.  I.E., you can actually watch the OS boot, or reinstall the OS with it.

Comment: I don't suppose this server is a member of an active directory domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need either:

- someone with physical access to go undo what you did
- or to roll back your virtual machine to an earlier state, which you might be able to do from a separate management console (depending on the provider)

There's nothing you can do at the machine level itself once the Firewall's in No Exceptions mode - that's like saying "I locked my keys in the bank vault; is there a back way in (without a lock) that I can use to get my keys back?"

The machine can connect outbound (for eg, to a remote desktop or sync service), but chances are it's not configured to do so.